# Script on bash, can you?

Tags: linux, bash

There is a string `$STRING`, in which syllables are written with the spaces. If the variable `$WORD` have at least one syllable in this string, report of this in any way.

Comment: -1 http://www.emilvikstrom.se/whyidownvote.html What is your question? What does your code look like and what errors do you get?

Comment: My error in my question, and my future code there too.

Comment: Your english is hard to understand. Try google translator.

Comment: Its a google traslator result, sorry

Comment: Please give a clearer description of your problem.

Comment: Looks like homework, is it? What have you tried?

Comment: I would try to pass these variables to python through it's cmd line interpreter and use the NLTK for natural language processing. Take a look at [google groups page on using NLTK to find syllables](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/nltk-users/mCOh_u7V8_I) to give you an idea of how it would work.

Comment: thx, but i need this script on bash

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer and mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution checks to see if `$WORD` exists in `$STRING` when it should be the other way around. Try this:

```
string="run walk stand"
word=walking
if echo "$string" | sed -e 's/ /\n/g' | grep -Fqif - <(echo "$word")
then
    echo "Match!"
fi
```

As you can see, you can test the result of the `grep` without having to save the output in a variable.

By the way `-n` is the same as `! -z`.